# jQuery variable inside .each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code

```
var temp = "text " + this.link + " text";

$(data.query.results.item).each(function () {
    alert(temp);
});
```

When alerted it returns "text undefined text"

But if i do this

```
$(data.query.results.item).each(function () {
    alert("text " + this.link + " text");
});
```

It returns the correct value

Why is this happening and how can i get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: What is the scope of this in your first example?

Comment: what is this.link in first code snippet ?

Comment: if `temp` is a global variable then `this` would refer to the `window` object.

Comment: this.link refers to data.query.results.item

Answer (score 1):

`this.link` is not accessible from the outside of the `each` loop. You can get access `this` context only from teh `each` scope. If you want to define some "template" ouside of the loop, you can try with:

```
var temp = "text %link% text";

$(data.query.results.item).each(function () {
    alert(temp.replace('%link%', this.link));
});
```

Comment: what if that `.each` has been wrapped around another one `.each` ..?

Comment: So what if i wante to put in the template more, like var temp = "text %link% text %image% text %title%". How can i replace all these without declaring this.link, this.image, this.title inside each.

Comment: @DimitrisBorbotsialos You have to bound key `%...%` with value `this....`, so for `text %link% text %image% text %title%` it should be `temp.replace('%link%', this.link).replace('%image%', this.image).replace('%title%', this.title)`

Comment: Thanks for your time. The thing is that i tried to use John Resig's micro template engine for this purpose. I've posted the original question but no answer yet here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757090/custom-jquery-rss-feed-plugin-with-micro-template If you have the time take a look of what i try to accomplish. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`this` refer to the context/scope where it is executed, your `this` is executed outside of each, that is why it is undefined -

You can try something like this -

```
function getText(item){
  var temp = "text " + item.link + " text";
}

$(data.query.results.item).each(function () {
    alert(getText(this));
});
```

Comment: I would go further and pass only `this.link` to the `getText` function.

Comment: @hsz sure, but item may have another properties that OP might want to include in text (_in future_)

Comment: On the other hand - it cannot be used for other kind of item. We can only speculate. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` always refers to the current object.

```
var temp = "text " + this.link + " text";
```

Here `this` is undefined that's why it's showing that message.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use each method in this way!

```
$.each(data.query.results.item, function( index, value ) {
    alert( "text " + value.link );
});
```